# when i try to change my <p> tag for the company name it also moves the nav bar buttons with it, is there a way to stop this happening?

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS for the Nav bar, anytime I change the ".navbar p" which includes the company name for the website it will also move all my Navbar buttons down the page.

```css
.navbar {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.navbar p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 6px 13px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="backpic">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <p> Painting & Decorators </p>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Previous Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Try avoiding the use of p tag inside the navbar, p tag is specifically used for large paragraph texts, instead of p tag try using div or span. By default p has some margin which is applied by the browser.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code as well?

Comment: added the html :)

Comment: I moved you code into a live demo. Is your site responsive?

Comment: the navbar is responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `navbar p` an inline element by using `display:inline`. It is taking the full-width, that's why the links are going to next line

```css
.navbar {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.navbar span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.navbar ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 6px 13px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="backpic">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <p>Painting & Decorators</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Previous Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of p tag you should have used span or div tag, which maintains accessibility, browser will read this test as paragraph. It is good practise to maintain accessibility while developing websites and encouraging others as well to implement accessibility.

Comment: Dear @ideekaye : Would like to tell you that. <p> is the block-level element and it takes full width of the container. Also you can avoid using floats for ever. Learn flexbox that makes things a lot easy. :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `<span> </span>` tag instead of the `<p> </p>` tag.
You can also assign an id to access the `<span>` or `<p>` tag.